# Enterprise Mobile SSO On Android

Tags: android, single-sign-on, enterprise

I have around three to four enterprise mobile applications targeted for employees of an organization. We would like to implement something like SSO, where you login with any of the applications, the other applications need not login. Also when you logout in any of the application the same has to be reflected in other applications as well.

I tried googling on this, I'm sure on which is the best approach for implementing the same.

1. **Content Provider**: 
   Using content provider, we have to make one of the applications as **master** which gives us the data needed to other applications. But here raises a query on **what will happen if the master application is uninstalled?**
2. **Shared Preferences**:
   I also noted that applications can access other apps Shared Preferences, by defining userid for applications. But again here we use the concept of **master** which has the same flaw of application getting uninstalled, or what if the no of applications grows.

Isnt there a common repository there all the applications from the same developer can share, and repository will be available till the last application of the developer is uninstalled. **Am I missing something here?**

I was also looking for SDKs which does the SSO for mobile apps like **[Layer7](http://www.layer7tech.com/solutions/mobile-single-sign-on)** . Has anyone worked on any such SDKs? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to go with Centrify SDK solution for ios and Android - http://developers.centrify.com, which provides authentication & SSO via its Centrify application on the device similar to "FB login" style. You install Centrify application from any of the app stores (Google Play or Apple Appstore), and then use Centrify SDKs to integrate your apps for authentication via Centrify app. With this solution, you can claim Active Directory support into your enterprise application and add-on bonus is SSO for all of them.

Centrify App, Centrify SDKs are FREE.

Disclaimer: I work for Centrify.